# ko computed not showing in view

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, computed-observable

I have some problems regarding binding to computed value. I am showing data in table, and summing up some fields. In footer I want to display the sum of those fields, and the empty column, as well as one with text of total. The values get stored inside of fields, as well as updated when the value of the referenced fields changes, but it doesn't show in the view. I know that I did something wrong with ko.computed, but I can't pinpoint what would that be.

HTML code:

```
    <table>
    <caption><h4 class="pull-left">Caption</h4></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: ColModel">
            <th data-bind="text: Caption"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: model, as: 'row' }">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.ColModel, as: 'col' }">
            <td data-bind="text: row[col.Field], css: { hidden: col.InSum != false }">

            </td>
            <td data-bind="css: { hidden: col.InSum != true }">
                <input type="number" step="any" class="input-small" data-bind="value:row[col.Field], valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: footmodel">
            <td data-bind="text: Value">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Iin my JS I have

```
clientViewModel.ColModel = ko.observableArray([
    {
        Caption: 'cap1',
        InSum: false,
        Field: 'FLD1'
    },
    {
        Caption: 'cap2',
        InSum: false,
        Field: 'FLD2'
    },
    {
        Caption: 'capsum1',
        InSum: true,
        Field: 'fldsum1'
    },
    {
        Caption: 'capsum2',
        InSum: true,
        Field: 'fldsum2'
    }
]);     
clientViewModel.model = ko.observableArray();
clientViewModel.footmodel = ko.observableArray([
    {
        Value: '',
        IsSum: false
    },
    {
        Value: 'total',
        IsSum: false
    },
    {
        Value: '',
        IsSum: true,
        SumField: 'fldsum1'    
    },
    {
        Value: '',
        IsSum: true,
        SumField: 'fldsum2'
    }
]);
```

ajax function is just a tiny wrapper around $.ajax function which we use in project to fetch data.

```
ajax('modelurl'),
    'GET',
    true,
    function (data, status) {
        $.each(data.Records, function (index, value) {
            var observableValue = makeObservable(value, clientViewModel.ColModel);
            clientViewModel.model.push(observableValue);
        });
        $.each(clientViewModel.footmodel(), function (index, value) {
            if (value['IsSum']) {
                clientViewModel.footmodel()[index]['Value'] = ko.computed(function () {
                    var sum = 0;
                    $.each(clientViewModel.model(), function (i, data) {
                        sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(data[value['SumField']]());
                    });
                    return sum.toString();
                }, clientViewModel);
            }
            else
                value['Value'] = ko.observable(value['Value']);
        });
});
```

Also, makeObservable is used to make the fields of an object observable. As I found out, all the fields that are connected to computed should be observable, thus the update can trigger.

```
function makeObservable(model, fields) {
    var ret = {};
    $.each(fields(), function (index, value) {
        ret[value.Field] = ko.observable(model[value.Field]);
    })
    return ret;
}
```

What is going on is unknown to me. Observable fields of the footmodel get printed out, while computed don't. All the fields of clientViewModel.model observable array are observable, the values get calculated, but they don't get printed out. What is the reason for that?

One possible solution, as far as I see it, could be to trigger the function that calculates the values to be summed and stores it in the observable field, that should get printed out OK. But I would rather make it work this way, and find out what causes this behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle with an example of your problem? I'm finding this very hard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you init `ko.applyBindings(...)` outside the ajax call, which means

```
<tr data-bind="foreach: footmodel">
    <td data-bind="text: Value"> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

The `text: Value` binds to the original empty string, even you replace the content of the `Value` in ajax with a `ko.computed(...)`, the binding system doesn't know.

To fix it, use an `if` binding to force knockout to re-parse the binding (the whole table) after ajax.

**HTML**

```
<!-- ko ifnot: loading -->
  <table> ... </table>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**JS**

```
clientViewModel.loading = ko.observable(false);

// begin ajax
clientViewModel.loading(true); // ko removes the table from DOM

$.ajax({...,
  success: function(data, status) {
   //... built your ko.computed
  },
  complete: function() {
   // finish ajax
   clientViewModel.loading(false); // ko re-creates the table in DOM
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey man. Thank you, this really works. I set up loading to false on the start, when I start fetching data I set it to true, and when I finish loading data in the last ajax call, I set it to false again. I'd upvote you, but my rep is too low, so someone else will have to :)

Comment: Yeah, forgot to do that, sorry, rushed to set this up on a test server :) Now it's fixed :)